# Dealing with missing values in SQL Server with Binary Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm building a file, using `SSMS`, that will be an input to a machine learning program.  The output file will be the result of a query of several tables in a `SQL Server 2008 R2 Express` DB.

The query results in `NULL` values for some of the cells.  Currently I'm using the `ISNULL()` function to insert `'0.00'` when there is a `NULL` value but this is just a temporary measure as some values are actually `'0.00'` and this skews the calculation.

What raw data would look like:

```
  id        surveyResponseRate      personResponseRate
 001            .068                      .15
 002            0.00                     NULL
 003            .014                      .03
 004            NULL                      .20
 005            .068                     0.00
 ...             ...                      ...
```

What current process creates:

```
 id        surveyResponseRate      personResponseRate
 001            .068                      .15
 002            0.00                     0.00
 003            .014                      .03
 004            0.00                      .20
 005            .068                     0.00
 ...             ...                      ...
```

I'm curious if there's a way to create a binary column that is `0` if the value is actually `0.00` and `1` if it's actually `0.00` due a `NULL` value.

What I'd like to see:

```
 id        surveyResponseRate      personResponseRate  survRRNA      perRRNA
 001            .068                      .15              0            0
 002            0.00                     0.00              0            1
 003            .014                      .03              0            0
 004            0.00                      .20              1            0
 005            .068                     0.00              0            0
 ...             ...                      ...             ...          ...
```

Any suggestions for how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add expressions for the new columns to the SELECT clause like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  ISNULL(surveyResponseRate, 0) AS surveyResponseRate,
  ISNULL(personResponseRate, 0) AS personResponseRate,
  CASE WHEN surveyResponseRate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS survRRNA,
  CASE WHEN personResponseRate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS perRRNA
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a store procedue to assign a value based on another rowvalue. But this is on the database side, dont know if this is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The columns `survRRNA` and `perRRNA` should be tri-state: NULL, 0.00, something else.

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `SELECT` for these new columns, to achieve this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN surveyResponseRate IS NULL then 1
    WHEN surveyResponseRate = 0.00 then 0
    ELSE -1
END as 'survRRNA'
```